# How to get Swagger to differentiate top-level from nested classes having the same name

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have a top-level Foo class:

```
public class Foo {
   int a;
   int b;
}
```

...and another top-level Bar class with its own nested Foo class:

```
public class Bar {
    Bar.Foo myBarFoo;

    public static class Foo {
        int c;
    }
}
```

These classes are used in request bodies for REST endpoints.

When generating the Swagger client, Swagger creates just one "Foo" class with the member variables of both Foo objects combined:

```
"Foo": {
"type": "object",
"properties": {
   "a": {"type": "integer","format": "int32"},
   "b": {"type": "integer","format": "int32"},
   "c": {"type": "integer","format": "int32"},
},
"title": "Foo"
},
```

Which is problematic as not all properties are valid for both usages.

If I use a different name for Foo in the nested class, say Foo2, then Swagger generates two distinct objects, so the problem goes away.

My question is, can I still generate distinct objects via Swagger codegen while keeping both class names as "Foo"?  If not, I'll go ahead and use distinct names.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  Assuming no way of doing this, I renamed Bar.Foo, but created an empty nested subclass of it as well, to minimize the amount of class renaming that would have to be done throughout the application:

```
public class Bar {
    Bar.Foo2 myBarFoo;

    public static class Foo2 {
        int c;
    }

    public static class Foo extends Foo2 {}
}
```

Swagger codegen creates a new Foo2 object for clients to use with just the "c" property, and the top level Foo goes back to just having "a" and "b".  Due to the added subclass, most of the app could continue using Bar.Foo without needing to use Bar.Foo2.